# mark the particular checkbox if condition is true using html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, checkbox

I am a newbie, and i need to mark a particular checkbox depending on query result

```
<c:forEach var="compnent" items="${compnents}">         
  <input type="checkbox" name="comp[]" value=${compnent}> ${compnent}
</c:forEach>
```

"compnents" - getting this value from controller class.It contains list of components which i am getting from a query

I will be using one more query to get list of components which are to be checked.

For Eg: with query1, i get the list of components which are say, comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4. So i get 4 checkboxes for each component. And all are not checked.

With query2, i get another list of components say, comp2, comp3. So comp2 and comp3 shd be marked and comp1 and comp4 shd not be marked.

FYI: I am using javascript and jquery to render the UI page

Could anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made used of JSP tag `<c:if>`

```
> <c:if test="${compnent.mark == 1}"> <input type="checkbox"
> value=${compnent.comp} checked> ${compnent.comp} </c:if> <c:if
> test="${compnent.mark == 0}"> <input type="checkbox"
> value=${compnent.comp}> ${compnent.comp} </c:if>
```

Here i am getting component from a query. component has 2 parts: component and mark(indicates whether to mark the check box).

So i am comparing component.mark, if it is 1 then i will check the box else i will just display.